# How to store Flutter's TimeOfDay value in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can I write and read Flutter's TimeOfDay value in Firestore?
TimeOfDay is a value representing a time during the day, independent of the date that day might fall on or the time zone.

Should I convert it to a string ("13:30")?

Answer (score 1):

The best option that you have is to save the date and time as a [Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

If you only need to use the time, then you can simply get it out by calling [toDate](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp/toDate.html). Inside the [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) class you'll find two useful properties [hour](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-core/DateTime/hour.html) and [minute](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.6/dart-core/DateTime/minute.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `TimeOfDay` to `DateTime` then to store `DateTime.toIsoString`..()

Comment: No, please don't store time as strings in the database.  Store them as Firebase Timestamps, which you can get with Timestamp.fromDate(aDateTime)